# Executar Xdebug no netbeans para debugar o Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, xdebug

Estou tentando debugar uma app no codeigniter atraves do xdebug no Netbeans. No entanto ao rodar minha app em modo debug, não consigo chegar aos meus controllers nem em nenhum breakpoint apos a primeira linha do index.php do codeigniter.

Estou rodando o codeigniter 3.0, no xampp e com o netbeans 8.1.

No meu php.ini as config estão assim:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_port= 9000
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
```

E nas configs do projeto no codeigniter esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem já teve este problema? O erro acontece so com o codeigniter qualquer outra aplicacao eu consigo debugar normalmente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se na configuração do debuger está marcado `break at first line`

Comment: com esta opção marcada ele para na primeira linha, sem ela ele nao para em breakpont nenhum.

Comment: Tenta mandar a query string p ver se ele entra no break point, chame seu sistema no navegador e adicione `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug`

Comment: mesmo executando dessa forma, a cada novo controller que eu chamo na minha app sempre para na primeira linha do index.php do CI,. Muito estranho o debug mesmo com breakpoint não parar a aplicacao.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema

Na configuracoes avancadas no menu de **executar configuracoes** eu deixei para depurar a URL na opção default, e no mapeamento do caminho eu deixei em branco.

Não sei o porque, mas quando crio o projeto este mapeamento do caminho fica preenchido e retirando ele o debug passou tranquilamente ate chegar nos breakpoints dos meus controllers.

No mais, obrigado pela ajuda do grande amigo [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]